# I'm trying to create a number guessing game but when I run this it keeps running the while loop and doesnt break out

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a number guessing game but when I run this it keeps running the while loop and doesnt break out. (very new to python by the way) thanks!

```
from random import randint
name1 = input("What is Player One's first name? ")
name2 = input("What is Player Two's first name? ")
cnumber = randint(1,25)
guess1 = ""
guess2 = ""
times_guessed1 = 0
times_guessed2 = 0

while guess1 != cnumber and guess2 != cnumber:
    guess1 = input(name1 + " guess a number between 1 and 25: ")
    times_guessed1 += 1
    guess2 = input(name2 + " guess a number between 1 and 25: ")
    times_guessed2 += 1

if guess1 == cnumber:
    print (name1, "wins!")
    print ("You guessed,", times_guessed1, "times.")
elif guess2 == cnumber:
    print (name2, "wins!")
    print ("You guessed,", times_guessed2, "times.")
```

Comment: Convert the input to `int`, or `cnumber` to `string`.

Comment: you probably have to cast guess1 and guess2 to int

Comment: @chillturtle never mind. However there's still another issue; if they both guess correctly, the `print (name2, "wins!")` line will never run, since it's in an `elif` statement rather than an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a `str`.

`randint(1,25)` returns an `int`.

When it compares, '2' with 2, it will be false in python.

Solution: convert the input to `int` like below.

```
guess1 = int(input(name1 + " guess a number between 1 and 25: "))
guess2 = int(input(name2 + " guess a number between 1 and 25: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` will return a string use `int(input())` to covert to int to be able to match with `randint`

Answer (score 0):

cnumber  is an int, but guess1 and guess2 are strings, so they are never equal, because their types are different. The easiest would be to convert cnumber to a string: `cnumber = str(randint(1,25))`.

Comment: The advantage of converting cnumber is, that your program does not crash if something that can not be converted to int is entered.